# Optimization of Recursive Pascal Triangle Function

Tags: python

Today I challenged myself to try and implement a recursive function that would produce Pascal's Triangle up to n levels. I managed to come up with a solution, however, it is not as efficient or elegant as I would like. In the following code, each time I call pascal_row() in pascal(), it has iterate through whatever number of levels is passed to pascal_row(); opposed to having it go through and build the triangle in n levels. I don't know if that makes sense, but here is the code... is there anyway to optimize this?

```
#builds the pascal row for the specified level
#ex. pascal_row(3) --> [1,3,3,1]
def pascal_row(levels):
    if levels == 0:
        return [1]
    elif levels == 1:
        return [1,2,1]
    else:
        row = []
        row.append(1)
        prev = pascal_row(levels-1)
        for i in range(len(prev)):
            try:
                row.append(prev[i] + prev[i+1])
            except:
                pass
        row.append(1)
        return row

#prints out pascal triangle up to specified level
def pascal(levels):
    for lvl in range(levels):
        print(pascal_row(lvl))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pascal(10)  #outputs correctly
```

Comment: I admire your want to optimize your program, but right now the way you are asking your question lends itself to a broadness that seems as though you are looking more for a coding service, which SO is not. So I have to flag this post. This may be better for Code Review on stack exchange.

Comment: My  apologies. Thank you.

Comment: No need to be sorry at all, just trying to point you in the right direction! I hope you find the help you are looking for!

Comment: @ThatGuyRussell: I don't believe there is a need to flag this. I would close it as too broad.

Comment: @Dair That is what I did, flagged it as too broad

Comment: To elaborate on why it is too broad: There are numerous optimizations that can be made, for example python is not well suited to recursion, maybe consider rewriting it using loops to make the code faster, maybe also consider memoizing some of the functions. There are still more optimizations than this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do, is cache intermediate calculations (a.k.a dynamic programming).

define a global variable

```
pascal_cache={0:[1],1:[1,2,1]}
```

Then modify `pascal_row`

```
def pascal_row(levels):
    if levels in pascal_cache.keys():
        return pascal_cache[levels]
    else:
        row = []
        row.append(1)
        prev = pascal_row(levels-1)
        for i in range(len(prev)):
            try:
                row.append(prev[i] + prev[i+1])
            except:
                pass
        row.append(1)
        pascal_cache[levels]=row
        return row
```

It should reduce the complexity of the code drastically

Answer (score -1):

even better:

```
pascal_reeks={0:[1],1:[1,2,1]}

if n in pascal_reeks:
    return pascal_reeks[n]
else:
    row = []
    row.append(1)
    prev = pascalTriangle(n-1)
    for i in range(len(prev) - 1):
        row.append(prev[i] + prev[i+1])

    row.append(1)
    pascal_reeks[n]=row
    return row
```